# Spring Batch with two Steps in flow. Why second step never run and first step is in infinite loop

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-scheduled

My requirements: create a scheduler to call the batch periodically and, inside of the batch, I need two steps. StepA will start run and accordingly to the outcome, StepB will called.
If you look at the Console Log you will see that the stepA is been called several time in, let's say, exact same moment. According to @Scheduled(fixedRate=60000) there should be just one call in each minute. Iguess that the problem has no relationship with Scheduller since I removed the schedulling and I faced similiar issue. Other related problem is that StepB is never called. I tried to create customDecider ("...next(customDecider()") and to create a private method to return JobExecutionDecider. It seems that both didn't take effect at all.
My best guess is that the pool-thread is causing some "infinite loop" in StepA because I didn't setup something properly but I didn't find what could be it.

BatchConfig.java

```
   /*@Bean
   public JobExecutionDecider customDecider() throws Exception{
          return new CustomDecider();
   }*/

   private JobExecutionDecider decider(boolean decision){
          return(jobExecution, stepExecution) -> new FlowExecutionStatus(decision ? "OK" : "FAILED");
   }


   @Bean
   public Job job(Step stepA, Step stepB) {
          return jobBuilderFactory.get("job1")
                       //.flow(stepA).on("FAILED").to(stepB).end().build();
                        .start(stepA)
                        .next(decider(true))
                        .on("FAILED")
                        .stop()
                        .from(stepA)
                        .next(stepB)
                        .build()
                        .build();

   }

   @Bean
   public Step stepA(ItemReader<String> readerA, ItemWriter<String> writerA) {
          return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepA").<String, String> chunk(1)
                       .reader(readerA)
                       .writer(writerA)
                       .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                       .build();

   }

   @Bean
   @StepScope
   public ItemReader<String> readerA() {
          return new CustomItemReaderA();

   }

   @Bean
   public ItemWriter<String> writerA() {
          return new CustomItemWriterA();

   }

   @Bean
   public Step stepB(ItemReader<String> readerB, ItemWriter<String> writerB) {
          return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepB").<String, String> chunk(1)
                       .reader(readerB)
                       .writer(writerB)
                       .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                       .build();

   }

   @Bean
   @StepScope
   public ItemReader<String> readerB() {
          return new CustomItemReaderB();

   }

   @Bean
   public ItemWriter<String> writerB() {
          return new CustomItemWriterB();

   }
```

CustomDecider.java

```
public class CustomDecider implements JobExecutionDecider  {


       @Override
       public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution,
                     StepExecution stepExecution) {
              return new FlowExecutionStatus("OK");
       }

}

CustomItemReaderA 

public class CustomItemReaderA  implements ItemReader<String>{

       private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomItemReaderA.class);
       @Override
       public String read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException,
                     ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
              log.info("rA");
              return "A";
       }

}

CustomItemWriterA 
public class CustomItemWriterA  implements ItemWriter<String>  {

       private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomItemWriterA.class);
       @Override
       public void write(List<? extends String> items) throws Exception {
              log.info("wA");

       }

}
```

CustomItemReaderB  and CustomItemReaderB are identical to Custom...A just changing from A to B letters during log.info and return

Console Log

```
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.488  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.504  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReaderA            : rA
2016-01-18 21:40:37.519  INFO 7340 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemWriterA            : wA
and so on ...
```

Scheduler

```
@Component
public class QueueScheduler {

       private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory
                     .getLogger(QueueScheduler.class);

    private Job job;
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    public QueueScheduler(JobLauncher jobLauncher, @Qualifier("job") Job job){
        this.job = job;
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
   }



   @Scheduled(fixedRate=60000)
   public void runJob(){
          try{
       jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
          }catch(Exception ex){
                 log.info(ex.getMessage());
          }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is with your `CustomItemReaderA`. You need to tell the Reader when to stop 'reading' for data. If you modify the reader as given below, the execution will happen as expected.

```
public class CustomItemReaderA implements ItemReader<String> {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(CustomItemReaderA.class);
    private int readCount = 0;

    @Override
    public String read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException,
            ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        log.info("Inside CustomItemReaderA");
        if (readCount == 1) {
            return null;
        }
        readCount++;
        return "Read CustomItemReaderA";
    }
}
```

Comment: So, is by returning null the only way to stop CustomItemReaderA? In order to avoid duplicate calls (the second only for return null) I can create a logic in order to return null if the first time was well-succeed. If ItemReader was designed with such idea in mind, that is ok for this scenario but, let's say there was a CustomItemProcessorA expecting the read data from CustomItemReaderA and CustomItemWriterA expecting the processed data from CustomItemReaderB, wouldn't return null break the purpose of such batch or force me to make an ugly workaround? Or  is it a must to read at least twice?

Comment: Other doubt very close the last one: in my requirement, I have to decide according to the CustomItemReaderA if CustomItemReaderB will be called. For this, I understand I have to use someway JobExecutionDecider and decide it via ...on(FlowExecutionStatus). How can I change the status from CustomItemReaderA? Well, thinking in just two options, (failed or succeed) I could use return null for well-succeed and throw exception for failed. But, let's think in three options? How do I return one of three status from CustomItemReaderA? Can I change FlowExecutionStatus from CustomItemReaderA?